# Matching survey database and member database

Tags: mysql, survey

I'm new to programming, and hope this question isn't too basic.  I've searched the questions here but can't find anything exactly like it.

I'm making a website in which people have to complete a sign-in form and then answer a survey.  The survey answers will drive how the site performs for each user (there will be different monthly reminders in email personalized to the survey responses).  I have two MySQL databases, one for the sign-in and one for the survey.

How do I get the member ID in the member database to be the same as the survey ID in the survey database?  Or am I thinking about this all wrong, and there's another solution?

I'm most familiar with PHP and JavaScript, so I hope that there will be a way to do this in the coding if not in the database design.  Again, sorry if this is too basic and many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terribly generic question to answer, but I hope I can help you a little along:

Now, assuming that you have a good reason for separating the user registration and the surveys in two different databases (you did not give a reason for it being so), after a successful user registration you can assume that the user is 'logged in'. This should mean that the ID of the registered user is available to you in code.

You do not have to have identical survey IDs and user IDs, it usually makes more sense to have a separate table knitting users and surveys together (with a `user_id` field and a `survey_id` field).

After setting up or saving the survey, store a record in this table, connecting the user with the survey.

If you were hoping for a more specific answer, I suggest you delve into a little more detail in your question.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this response!  I will put the tables together into one database (there was no reason for that . . . just inexperience).  Just curious--why is it beter to have the separate table knitting the two together, rather than making the IDs the same?  Thank you.

Comment: Again, this depends on the purpose - if one user row should always be connected with one survey row, why not keep everything in the same table?Having a separate table is most often used in many-to-many relationships, in which one user can be connected to many surveys, and one survey can be connected to many users. This might not make sense in your situation, though.

Comment: @Nils: Two tables is perfectly fine. Even in 1:1 relationships. Foreign keys across multiple databases work too in Mysql (as long as the storage engine supports those).

Comment: @hakre: Sure it is, but what is the point if you do not have a good reason for it? In addition, for an inexperienced developer like the original poster struck me to be, it will be helpful to keep the database as simple as possible.

Comment: @Nils: Fair point. Actually the question itself is a bit troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Just some hints, they won't rock the house but probably good for a start:

- Put the two tables in the same database. This is less a technical requirement, but it's easier for you. The two tables belong together, keep them in the same database.
- It's okay to have two tables.
- The member ID and the survey ID do not need to be the same. Instead add a `memberID` column to the *survey* table and set it to the appropriate `ID` of the *member* table.